# PHP: how to echo nth value of basic XML string

Tags: php, xml, echo

I have a PHP object containing an XML string that looks as follows. 
How can I echo the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th value out of this using PHP ?

**My XML:**

```
<ranks>
  <groupCount>0</groupCount>
  <groupCount>5</groupCount>
  <groupCount>8</groupCount>
  <groupCount>14</groupCount>
  <groupCount>15</groupCount>
  <groupCount>15</groupCount>
</ranks>
```

If I use `<?php echo $objMyObject->groupCount; ?>` then this returns the first value correct so I just need a way for the others.

Many thanks for any help, Mike.

Comment: What happens when you do `print_r($objMyObject);`?

Comment: Can you show you code? It is unclear whether you have done anything to parse the XML into an object or whether you are talking about `groupCount` being a property on your object that contains this XML string.

Comment: Thanks. Printing the whole object returns the following: SimpleXMLElement Object ( [groupCount] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 [3] => 14 [4] => 15 [5] => 15 ) )

Comment: Well - I assume you know how to print the elements of an array...

Comment: @Floris To be fair, it's not an array, just an object with a lot of magic methods defined. In this case, the `print_r` is helpful, but often it's misleading (hiding things like CDATA nodes, text where there are also children, and namespaced elements, for instance).

Comment: @imsop fair point - but looking at the output gives a hint for things you could try and "hey look! It works!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml), you can just access it as though there was a numeric array:

```
// The first item is this...
echo $objMyObject->groupCount;
// ... but also this
echo $objMyObject->groupCount[0];
// The 6th item would be this
echo $objMyObject->groupCount[5];

// Or you can loop over them all like this
foreach ( $objMyObject->groupCount as $i => $count ) {
     echo 'The ', $i+1, 'th item is ', $count;
}
```

See [more examples in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).